# Preventing others from force-pushing to my Git repository

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to prevent anybody except me from force-pushing to one of my Git repositories (in Github, specifically)?

It's my understanding that protected branches protect against force-pushing entirely, but I'm fine as long as I'm the one doing it.

Comment: This could be done if you could get collaborators to install a pre-push hook.

Comment: As soon as anyone else but you uses your branch (read or write) your force-pushing causes that they cannot pull anymore but need to clone every time something changes. So I don't see the usecase here. Maybe it would help if you add a bit more context.

Comment: A co-worker fetched a branch X in my repo, fixed a bug, then interactive rebased the branch for some reason and force-pushed it back to my repo. Meanwhile, I had some other branches off of X before it was rebased so now those branches have merge conflicts. I'm fine with being able to force push to my own repo because I know what's connected to what (and I use `git commit --amend` a lot) but I'd like other people to ask me first before mucking with it.

Comment: Related: [Elegant solution to prevent force push on master only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7419244/4561887)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever there is a protection issue on a GitHub repo, the surest way to enforce it is to have... two repos.

- One where you are the only collaborator (and can do force pushes)
- one **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)**, where collaborators can still force pushes, but will have to rebase their PR (pull requests) branch on top of *your* branches, in order to submit their pull requests.
  They would use a [triangular workflow](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows#improved-support-for-triangular-workflows).

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1319791/8943755/5dcdcae4-354a-11e5-9f82-915914fad4f7.png]

That way, you can control what gets into your repo.