# How to protect labels in gitlab from being deleted by other members?

Tags: gitlab

we are using gitlab with gold license. Like in all versions, there are [labels](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/labels.html#labels).

We have some groups / subgroups and projects. We share across some teams (subgroups) labels.

How can we avoid that LABELs are deleted by "the wrong" members?

- To protect the code there are obviously merge requests
- For branches I found the topic, solved with hooks, here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401155/git-how-to-protect-the-branch-from-being-removed-by-other-developers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to secure the git access depends on the users
Below is link which can guide you.

[See here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/26588)

[gitlab branch permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html)

[Git security branch](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/security-best-practices-for-git-users/)

Comment: is there sth. related to labels?